# REST API in SOA architecture, authorizing drupal to consume APIs

Tags: api, rest, drupal, oauth

So for our architecture we have drupal as a CMS. It is mandatory that it needs to consume a few APIs in a SOA REST architecture.

For example for:

- writing Logs
- writing into a LRS (Learning Storage System)
- writing user profiles data
- writing into a pubsub queue

Learning how it works. So many people are suggesting to use OAuth for this.

I am looking to understand more deeply:

- I register the drupal app with the OAuth server
- I get a client ID and a client Secret

Suppose I want to write a log. Do I send the client ID and secret to the log API, and the log API redirects the request to the Oauth server for a token?

Or do I contact the OAuth server first, request a token, and with that I go to the log API?

Do I need to do this for every request? Or do I request a token right away which is stored on the file system of drupal's machine?

Or should it be done entirely different? Is Basic Auth over SSL more efficient for this?

Sorry if this is all pretty obvious, I'm a learning noob on this. Most examples on the web I've found focus on using OAuth for authorization for user data like for g+, fb, github, etc. But what about a server requesting access to APIs...

Comment: logs in this context are more like audit logs, not regular app logs

Answer (score 0):

I'll put an own answer, please please please add more if you have better ideas! Also downvote it if it's nonsense.

I am thinking of using auth, register the app and getting client id and secret.

When the app starts up, it authenticates with the Oauth server, and gets a token. Subsequent requests send the token to the API endpoints, which validate the token.

Setting the token to be valid 1 day seems to be a sensible time span.

(Can the OAuth server be configured to issue tokens with different expiry time for different users/applications?)